# How can I batch process the gradient descent algorithm

Tags: matlab, minimization

The problem is to minimize this function

```
 f1(X)^2 + f2(X)^2 + f3(X)^2 + f4(X)^2
```

such that `L <= X <= U`

where `X` is a vector `X = [x1, x2]'`, `F = [f1, f2, f3, f4]'` are non-linear system of functions, `L` and `U` are the lower and upper bound of `X`.

I want to use gradient descent to estimate `X`. Is there a function in matlab to do this?

My particular concern is how to batch process gradient descent algorithms in matlab, because 
I have a huge number of cases in this form.

Answer (score 2):

for bounded optimization, checkout the `fmincon` function in matlab